# How to convert this function into laravel function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-4

How do I convert this recursive function into laravel fucntion. here is the error message

" array_filter() expects parameter 1 to be array, object given "

**Actual Function**

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM tasks";
$r = mysql_query($sql, $conn);
$arr = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($r))
   $arr[] = $row

function build($arrayIn, $parent)
{
    $makeFilter = function($p) {return function($x) use ($p) {return $x['parent'] == $p;};};
    $f = $makeFilter($parent);
    $these = array_filter($arrayIn, $f);
    $remaining = array_diff_assoc($arrayIn, $these);
    $ans = array();

    foreach($these as $cur)
    {
       $ans[$cur['text']] = build($remaining, $cur['id']);
    }
    return $ans ? $ans : null;
}

$tree = build($arr, 0)
echo_r($arr);
echo "becomes<br />";
echo_r($tree);
```

**My attempt** which is not working

```
$arr = USER::all();

function build($arrayIn, $parent)
{
    $makeFilter = function($p) {return function($x) use ($p) {return $x['parent'] == $p;};};
    $f = $makeFilter($parent);
    $these = array_filter($arrayIn, $f);
    $remaining = array_diff_assoc($arrayIn, $these);
    $ans = array();

    foreach($these as $cur)
    {
       $ans[$cur['text']] = build($remaining, $cur['id']);
    }
    return $ans ? $ans : null;
}

$tree = build($arr, 0)
echo_r($arr);
echo "becomes<br />";
echo_r($tree);
```

Answer (score 1):

As the error suggests, you are using an object when the function expects an array.
You can simply use the `toArray()` method to convert to an array:

```
$tree = build($arr->toArray(), 0);
```

http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#converting-to-arrays-or-json

Comment: Great thanks that worked got resolveded now its throwing ErrorException (E_UNKNOWN) Array to string conversion

Comment: @DanielEuchar What does `var_dump($arr->toArray());` output?

Comment: Well that output is the same format as the array in the original function. Does the original function actually work?